# Access data load failing in .net

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, oledb

I have a .net application that is not working on a colleagues computer (he works remotely so it's harder to diagnose the problem).  The error appears when data is being loaded from an Access database.  Here is the code I'm using to load the data:

```
var constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=X:\db.mdb";
OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(constring);
c.Open();
var dataSet = new DataSet();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table", c);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
c.Close();
```

What can cause an error at this stage?  Will this code break if Access isn't installed, or the wrong version?  What other things could cause this code to break?

Edit: Not C:\, but X:\, which is a shared network drive.

Comment: What error is it? Use breakpoints to narrow it right down the specific line that's giving you the headache.

Comment: Provide the actual error would help

Comment: @Daniel, his colleague is remote. Although that would definately help if it were possible

Comment: With such a set-up (with regards to remote applications) I'd have a system in place to handle and report any errors and exceptions a lot more informatively. I'd do the obvious checks first sooprise - check the file exists, check the table name etc.

Comment: File exists, table names are good (this is working on everyone else's machines).  I received a screen-shot of the error, but it's tiny and un-readable.  This is a pretty senior guy, so I'm trying to diagnose the problem without bugging him so much for more information.

Comment: @sooprise can't you run the same application locally to test the connection? What version of access is it? I use this for 2010: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\records2007.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Comment: Just to add, I can use the code posted in the question to connect to a Microsoft Access database and fill a dataset from C# so the code itself is fine.

Comment: Does this user has access to X: ??Maybe network drive was not up when he turned on the PC..

Comment: I'm goign to echo @gbianchi: you mention that the user is working remotely: is he accessing a local server or is he working on his desktop/laptop from somewhere other than the office? The fact that your database is on a shared drive `X:` would make me think that he doesn't have access to that drive, but of course you would. That or the `X:` share is not mounted on his machine, and you would be better to use a URI like `\\sharedMachine\mydb\db.mdb`. Another issue could be that he doesn't have the security credentials to access the share. Can he open the database directly from Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance;
- there is no provider in the machine
- there is no source file C:\db.mdb
- source file (database) is not proper (no table name Table)

Comment: Unless it a very old XP system, that provider should be present.. probably DB is not present...

Comment: Additionally, user might not have permissions to the file at c:\db.mdb

Comment: Db is not present?  What does this mean?  Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: The user had a drive mapped to a different drive letter than the one specified in the code.  The answer was just under my nose!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, since you haven't said what error you are having, this is just a guess:

I have seen many cases where Jet's performance over a VPN connection is painfully slow.  This often results in an attempt to read data timing out.  <s>Is the database *really* located at `C:\db.mdb`?  If it is on a network drive, t</s>  The adapter is probably timing out when it is filling the data set, especially if you have a fair amount of data in the table.

If this is the reason for your problem, you may be able to rewrite the application to retrieve only the records that it needs, when it needs them.

At my company, we have a computer sitting in our office for remote users to use our Access application.  They log in to that machine with remote desktop; since the machine is on our LAN, the performance is the same as for local users.

If you can add more detail to your question, we may be able to provide more useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled as "Any CPU" and your colleagues computer is running 64bit it will have problems connecting to the DB.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b5a79958-5bce-4229-a69f-75589b6240a8